# Can i automatically send a mail (Without the user need to approve)

Tags: android

Can i automatically send a mail (Without the user need to approve). I found some code only for gmail [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

Comment: If you are using the Internet Access you can just use IMAP or SMTP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now without using Intent (Without user interaction) you can send mail.

For this look at [Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

also [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default android app(Builtin Email application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap)

or [Sending email without user interaction in Android](http://nilvec.com/sending-email-without-user-interaction-in-android/).

Try this and let me know what happen,,

Thanks.